# jQuery Datatables prevent scroller reset on table reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I finally got my datatable to reload on intervals. But what I'm noticing now is if you scrolled to the right, the table reload will reset the scroll back to the left. The same if you are scrolled down, it will reset back to the top.

I need to stop this from happening.

I've tried all the answers from this post:  [How to maintain jQuery DataTables scroll position after .draw()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27663743/how-to-maintain-jquery-datatables-scroll-position-after-draw)

Nothing seems to work.  Maybe I'm missing something.

I noticed on this post, the question is using a datatables.scroller.min.js:  [DataTables save state scroll position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644170/datatables-save-state-scroll-position)

This led me to this:  https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/1.4.2/

But there are so many CSS files there.  I'm not sure which one to use, if any should be used at all.

Maybe I do not need any of the above, and I just need to adjust my code below to prevent the scroll reset from happening:

Click event:

```
$('.searchSubmit').on('click', function() {
  updateDataTable();

  var idle = 0;
  var idleInterval = setInterval(timer, 5000);
  $(this).mousemove(function(e){idle = 0;});
  $(this).keypress(function(e){idle = 0;});
  function timer()
  {
    idle = idle + 1;
    if(idle > 2)
    {
      updateDataTable();
      console.log('table reloaded'); 
    }
  }
});
```

Datatable:

```
function updateDataTable() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'api/railmbs.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
      var jsonObject = $.parseJSON(data); 
      var table = $('#example1').DataTable({    
        "data": jsonObject,
        "columns": [
          { "data": "BILL" },   
          { "data": "CONTAINER" },
          // few more columns
        ],
        "iDisplayLength": 25,
        "paging": true,
        "scrollY": 550,
        "scrollX": true,
        "bDestroy": true,
        "stateSave": true,  
        "autoWidth": true
      });
    },
    error: function(jqHHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
      console.log('fail');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: is not easier to use [`DataTable().ajax.reload()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload())? it will do what you0re currently doing and if you set up `reload(null, false)` it won't reset positions

Comment: I was initially using the method you are referring to, but I could not get the reload working properly.  However, if you wouldn't mind providing an example, I would at least try it.

Comment: @JohnBeasley "*but I could not get the reload working properly.*", because you didnt' pay attention to the answers and comments.

Comment: @davidkonrad - In regards to the DataTable().ajax.reload(), perhaps you could help me answer my previous post.  I was using the method as suggested but was receiving the error posted here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47418005/jquery-datatables-reload-interval-error   - Please do enlighten me, if you would.

Answer (score 1):

DOM elements have their current scroll state in `elem.scrollLeft/scrollTop`,[further reading](https://javascript.info/size-and-scroll-window#page-scroll)

try this code it rescued me.

```
var startPos = document.body.scrollLeft

 $(selector).DataTable().clear();
 $(selector).DataTable().ajax.reload(() => {

   document.body.scrollLeft = startPos;

  },false);
```

and for keeping maintaining vertical scroll state try this

```
 var startPos = document.body.scrollTop

 $(selector).DataTable().clear();
 $(selector).DataTable().ajax.reload(() => {

   document.body.scrollTop = startPos;

  },false);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635188/why-is-body-scrolltop-deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Using the [DataTable().ajax.reload()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()) will just init the datatable and then make it to reload on a interval (as you're doing currently)

```
 setInterval(function() {
   $('#example1').DataTable().ajax.reload(null, false);
 }, 5000);

$('#example1').DataTable({
  ajax: {
    url: "api/railmbs.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    dataSrc: function(data) {
      return $.parseJSON(data);
    }
  },
  "columns": [{
      "data": "BILL"
    }, {
      "data": "CONTAINER"
    },
    // few more columns
  ],
  "iDisplayLength": 25,
  "paging": true,
  "scrollY": 550,
  "scrollX": true,
  "bDestroy": true,
  "stateSave": true,
  "autoWidth": true
});
```

As per DataTables Documents `resetPaging` (the second parameter on false)

> Reset (default action or true) or hold the current paging position
>   (false). A full re-sort and re-filter is performed when this method is
>   called, which is why the pagination reset is the default action.

This means that neither the pagination(None than it matters if you have `scrollY`) nor the position of the scroll (X or Y) should reset.

Comment: I'll give it a shot and let you know how it turns out.

Comment: No luck.  Forgot I asked this question just the other day, using pretty much your example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47418005/jquery-datatables-reload-interval-error

Comment: @JohnBeasley what exactly doesn't seem to work for you when using this way? As with that same exmple is working for me, at least that you're adding some different data or things, about the `TypeError: g is null` not really sure but it has to do with paging or sending some variable null to reload.